# Unable to push Sample R Shiny App to Bluemix

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-rtwitter-app/) and when I go to "push" the sample application onto IBM Bluemix it fails in creating the instance. I am using a [custom buildpack](https://github.com/aruizga7/cf-buildpack-r) and that is successful in installing all the neccessary `R` files and etc.

My command to push the application onto Bluemix: `cf push MyNewShinyApp -b https://github.com/aruizga7/cf-buildpack-r.git`

The error  I receive is: `Failed to accept connection within health check timeout...` (on command prompt)

and on Bluemix I receive this error:

`an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout
exit status: 1, CRASHED`

Comment: Have you modified the source app at all from the example?

Comment: No I haven't modified any of the files from the Git

Comment: Is there a typo in the cf push command? Buildpack should be https://github.com/aruizga7/cf-buildpack-r

Comment: @AlexdaSilva I just typed it incorrectly on here, I entered the right buildpack on command prompt

Comment: Im getting the same thing as well...

Comment: @Sonam Wangyat, please check the hostname and domain name in manifest.yml.  It may be possible that you are using the hostname that is already present.

Comment: @KamaganahallyJaganatha I am having the same error as well.  The error you mention would be if there was an error message mentioning hostname was taken.

Comment: @KamaganahallyJaganatha I kept making different apps with different hostnames, so I don't think it could be that.

Comment: Can you run $ cf logs APP_NAME during deployment to access the deployment logs and look for more information?

Comment: `2015-09-22T16:45:35.81-0400 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/cf-buildpack-r'...
2015-09-22T16:45:39.28-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Vendoring R 3.1.0
2015-09-22T16:45:39.30-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Downloading and unpacking R binaries
2015-09-22T16:48:21.63-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Directory created, R pulled, unpacked
2015-09-22T16:48:25.36-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Stuff copied
2015-09-22T16:48:25.38-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        variables set
2015-09-22T16:48:25.41-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        environment copied`

Comment: `2015-09-22T16:48:25.44-0400 [STG/0]      ERR cat: /tmp/staged/app/init.r: No such file or directory
2015-09-22T16:48:25.46-0400 [STG/0]      OUT WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
2015-09-22T16:48:25.88-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     CRAN 
2015-09-22T16:48:25.88-0400 [STG/0]      OUT "@CRAN@" 
2015-09-22T16:48:25.92-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        R 3.1.0 successfully installed
2015-09-22T16:48:52.88-0400 [STG/145]    OUT -----> Uploading droplet (72M)
2015-09-22T16:49:01.80-0400 [DEA/145]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid be1423f7-dee1-443c-ba36-7531563b60ab`

Comment: `2015-09-22T16:49:18.96-0400 [DEA/145]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections`